# Replacement[] and Apply[], aren't commutative?

Tags: replacement

in my notebook, I have a function which output is of the kind:

```
zzz[0,{a,b,c},{d,e,f,g},OptionsPattern]
```

Then, I need to use this output in another form

```
xxxz[a,b,c,d,e,f,g]
```

My initial strategy was

```
zzz[0,{a,b,c},{d,e,f,g},OptionsPattern] /.zzz[0,a__,OptionsPattern]->xxx@@Join[a]
```

It turns out however that this is not joining the two arrays as required. However, it works if using a two-step approach

```
zzz[0,{a,b,c},{d,e,f,g},OptionsPattern]/.zzz[0,a__,OptionsPattern]->Join[a];
xxx@@%
```

Does anyone know the reason? Would be possible to do so in one step?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need `:>` instead of `->`

Comment: Use `RuleDelayed` instead of `Rule`, `:>` instead of `->`, and that might fix it.

Comment: Thanks, using `:>` instead worked perfectly :D